# Hint to prove that $\phi^n + \phi'^n$ is an integer.

Tags: induction, golden-ratio

I was solving some induction exercises but I found this that I could not solve.

> Let $n \in \mathbb{N}$, prove that $\phi^n + \phi'^n$ is an integer where $\phi=\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}$ and $\phi'=\frac{1-\sqrt{5}}{2}=-\frac{1}{\phi}$.

Any hint for the inductive step?

Comment: A fun alternate (and generalized) route: use induction to prove the fundamental theorem of symmetric polynomials, then apply here.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Hint** The inductive step will make use of $\varphi^2=\varphi+1$.

Answer (score 3):

$\phi$ and $\phi'$ are roots of $x^2-x-1$ which has integer coefficients and so *all* symmetric polynomial functions of $\phi$ and $\phi'$ are polynomials over $\mathbb Z$ in the coefficients of $x^2-x-1$ and so are integers. $\phi^n + \phi'^n$ is one such symmetric polynomial function.

If you don't want to use the [fundamental theorem of symmetric polynomials](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_symmetric_polynomial),
you can use [Newton's identities](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_identities), which are exactly what you need and much easier to prove.

This solution does not use induction but is much more interesting.

Answer (score 2):

Consider $1 = (\varphi + \frac{-1}{\varphi})^n$, use binomial expansion, and use induction.

Answer (score 0):

Calculate the first 5 or 6 values of $a_n=\phi^n + \phi'^n$. Can you predict $a_n$ for larger $n$ values without calculating higher and higher powers of $\phi$ and $\phi'$? Do you see a pattern to the numbers in the sequence $\{a_n\}$? Can you prove it's true for $\phi^n + \phi'^n$? Will a previously-offered hint help you do that?