# Why is $ (2+\sqrt{3})^n+(2-\sqrt{3})^n$ an integer?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory

Answers to [limit $\lim_{n\to ∞}\sin(\pi(2+\sqrt3)^n)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1901545/limit-lim-n-to-%E2%88%9E-sin-pi2-sqrt3n) start by saying that $ (2+\sqrt{3})^n+(2-\sqrt{3})^n $ is an integer, but how can one see that is true?

**Update:** I was hoping there is something more than binomial formula for cases like $ (a+\sqrt[m]{b})^n+(a-\sqrt[m]{b})^n $ to be an integer

Comment: Do you know the binomial formula?

Comment: @Arthur : yes , but is there something more fundemantal that $ (2+\sqrt[m]{3})^n+(2-\sqrt[m]{3})^n $ is integer?

Comment: Let $x \in \Bbb Q(\sqrt 3)$ be your number. Since $x$ is fixed by any $\sigma \in \text{Gal}(\Bbb Q(\sqrt 3)/\Bbb Q)$, we know by Galois theory that $x$ is rational. As it is an algebraic integer, it is an integer.

Comment: Related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/672212, http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/505414/hint-to-prove-that-phin-phin-is-an-integer, http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/726703, http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/906584/the-number-3-sqrt5n3-sqrt5n-is-an-integer

Comment: Choosing a basis for $ \mathbf Q(\sqrt{3})/\mathbf Q $ and writing the multiplication map by $ 2 + \sqrt{3} $ as a matrix, then interpreting the given quantity as the value of the field trace gives my argument in the answer.

Comment: It's pretty obvious because $\left(\, 2 + x\,\right)^{\, n} + \left(\, 2 - x\,\right)^{\, n}$ is an $\underline{even\ function}$ of $x$. @gammatester answer is the closest one to this fact.

Comment: @Arjang: however working with rational exponents doesn't give the same result, e.g. http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/89067

Comment: Related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/940517

Answer (score 14, accepted):

As an alternative to applying the binomial theorem (that is a fine way), the sequence given by
$$ a_n=(2+\sqrt{3})^n+(2-\sqrt{3})^n \tag{1}$$
fulfills
$$ a_0=2,\qquad a_1=4,\qquad a_{n+2}=4a_{n+1}-a_n \tag{2} $$
hence $a_n\in\mathbb{Z}$ is trivial by induction.
 In general, if $\eta,\xi$ are roots of a monic second-degree polynomial with integer coefficients,
$$ \eta^{n+2}+\xi^{n+2} = (\eta+\xi)(\eta^{n+1}+\xi^{n+1})-(\eta\xi)(\eta^n+\xi^n) \tag{3}$$
proves just the same, since $(\eta+\xi)\in\mathbb{Z}$ and $\eta\xi\in\mathbb{Z}$ are consequences of Viète's formulas.

Comment: It just remind me of the Fibonacci sequence.

Comment: @hkmather802 That's not so strange, seeing that the Fibonacci sequence may be written as $$F_n=\frac{1}{2}\left(\left(\frac{1+\sqrt5}2\right)^n+\left(\frac{1-\sqrt5}2\right)^n\right)$$

Comment: @Arthur Also, just for fun: $$F_{2n}\sqrt 5+1=\sqrt[3]{\bigg(\frac{\sqrt 5+1}2\bigg)^{6n}-\bigg(\frac{1-\sqrt 5}2\bigg)^{6n}+15F_{2n}^{\, 2}+1}$$ :)

Answer (score 15):

Hint: Let $a=(2+\sqrt{3})^n$ and $b=(2-\sqrt{3})^n$. Then $ab=(4-3)^n=1$. Also $a^{-1}=b$. Now conclude that $a+b=a+a^{-1}$ is integral.

Comment: This is a very elegant solution as it doesn't invoke more powerful tools such as the binomial theorem.

Comment: @user1892304 Thank you :)

Comment: Sorry if I am missing something obvious, but why is $a+a^{-1}$ an integer?

Comment: @DietrichBurde $a^2 + 1 = (7+4\sqrt3)^n + 1$. So $a+a^{-1} = \frac{(7+4\sqrt3)^n + 1}{(2+\sqrt3)^n}$. How to see that this is an integer? I hope I am not missing something obvious as is suggested by the number of up votes on your answer

Comment: Use induction. For $n=1$, $a+a^{-1}=4$.

Answer (score 14):

Consider the matrix

$$ A = \begin{bmatrix}
    2 & 3\\
    1 & 2
  \end{bmatrix} $$

Clearly $ A^n $ is a matrix with integer entries, therefore the trace $ \operatorname{tr} A^n $ is an integer. On the other hand, $ A $ is a diagonalizable matrix whose eigenvalues are $ \lambda_1 = 2 + \sqrt{3} $, $ \lambda_2 = 2 - \sqrt{3} $; therefore the eigenvalues of $ A^n $ are $ \lambda_1^n $ and $ \lambda_2^n $. Since the trace of a matrix is the sum of its eigenvalues, we conclude that $ \operatorname{tr} A^n = \lambda_1^n + \lambda_2^n $, and the quantity on the right hand side is an integer.

Answer (score 12):

Let $x \in \Bbb Q(\sqrt 3)$ be your number. Since $x$ is fixed by any $\sigma \in \text{Gal}(\Bbb Q(\sqrt 3)/\Bbb Q)$, we know by Galois theory that $x$ is rational. As it is an algebraic integer, it is an integer.

---

This can be used to show that
$$y=(3-2\cos(2\pi/7))^4+(3-2\cos(4\pi/7))^4+(3-2\cos(6\pi/7))^4$$ is also an integer ([$y=682$](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%283-2cos%282%CF%80%2F7%29%29%5E4%2B%283-2cos%284%CF%80%2F7%29%29%5E4%2B%283-2cos%286%CF%80%2F7%29%29%5E4)).

(The minimal polynomial of $2\cos(2\pi/7)$ over $\Bbb Q$ is $x^3+x^2-2 x-1$; the $3$ conjugates of
$2\cos(2\pi/7)=\zeta_7+\overline{\zeta_7}=\zeta_7+\zeta_7^{-1},$
 with $\zeta_7=e^{2\pi i /7}$, are of the form $\zeta_7^k+\zeta_7^{-k}=2\cos(2k\pi/7)$).

Comment: This is, of course, what's *really* happening.

Comment: Wow. $+1{}{}{}$

Answer (score 5):

Expand the sums using binomial expansion and all of the root terms disappear:
$$ (2+\sqrt 3)^n + (2-\sqrt 3)^n = 2^n\sum_{r=0}^{n} \binom {n}{r}(\frac {\sqrt 3}{2})^r+ 2^n\sum_{r=0}^{n}\binom {n}{r}(-1)^r(\frac {\sqrt 3}{2})^r$$
All of the terms corresponding to odd values of r are cancelled, leaving only two copies of the terms corresponding to even values of r.

$$(2+\sqrt 3)^n + (2-\sqrt 3)^n =2^{n+1}\sum_{r=0}^{n}\binom {n}{2r}(\frac {\sqrt 3}{2})^{2r}$$
Pulling down the factor of two in the power and multiplying the 2's inside the sum shows that the number must be an integer:
$$(2+\sqrt 3)^n + (2-\sqrt 3)^n =2^{n+1}\sum_{r=0}^{n}\binom {n}{2r}(\frac 34)^{r} = \sum_{r=0}^{n}\binom {n}{2r}3^{r}2^{n-r+1}$$
Since r is at most n, n-r+1 is at minimum 1. Thus there are no roots or negative exponents so it must be an integer.

This works for any (a+root(b))^n

Answer (score 5):

$2-\sqrt3$ and $2+\sqrt3$ are the roots of $a^2-4a+1=0$, hence your expression is the solution of the recurrence

$$a_{n+2}=4a_{n+1}-a_n$$ with $a_0=2,a_1=4$.

Obviously, all other terms are integer.

Answer (score 4):

Use the binomial theorem. $(-\sqrt{3})^{2k}=3^k$ and the odd-indexed terms cancel because
$(-\sqrt{3})^{2k+1}=-(\sqrt{3})^{2k+1}$

Answer (score 3):

Using the Newton identity,

$$
(2+\sqrt{3})^n + (2-\sqrt{3})^n = \sum_{i=0}^n \left(\binom{n}{i} 2^i\sqrt{3}^{n-i} + 2^i(-\sqrt{3})^{n-i}\right).
$$

The terms where $n-i$ is odd get elided, leaving you with terms where $2m = n-i$, which make $(\pm\sqrt{3})^{2m}$ an integer.

Answer (score 2):

Several answers. I add the mine because I want to say something about your **Update**.

If you apply the only (non trivial) automorphism of the quadratic field $\Bbb Q(\sqrt d)$ defined by $\sigma(a+b\sqrt d)=a-b\sqrt d$ you have
$$(a+b\sqrt d)^n=A_n+B_n\sqrt d \iff (a-b\sqrt d)^n=A_n-B_n\sqrt d$$ and you have finished taking the sum equal to $2A_n$.

This can not be verified if the irrational $\theta$ is not quadratic because the conjugate of $\theta$ is not unique (there are $k$ in total where $k$ is the degree of the concerned field). You can verified this for example with $\sqrt[3] 2$ whose conjugates are $\sqrt[3] 2$, $\sqrt[3] 2 j$ and $\sqrt[3] 2 j^2$ where $j^2+j+1=0$ (the non real cubic root of $1$).

Without using automorphisms you can see that even for $n=2$ you cannot have for $b\ne 0$

$$(a+b\sqrt[3] 2)^2+(a-b\sqrt[3] 2)^2\in \Bbb Z$$

Answer (score 2):

Pell equations are relevant to certain sequences, recurrence relations. E.g., see [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2309700/236182). I'll use a formula from the answer with $x_1,y_1,D$.

Sometimes a Pell equation doesn't seem to exist for a certain sequence, as seen in [this case](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2370412/236182) and [this case](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2370356/236182) (see the ends of the answers).

In this case, a Pell equation does exist.

Let $a_n=\frac{(2+\sqrt{3})^n+(2-\sqrt{3})^n}{2}$, $n\ge 0$, $n\in\mathbb Z$.

Then $b_n=2a_n$ ($n\ge 0$, $n\in\mathbb Z$) is the sequence of integers (you wanted to prove they're integers) you want.

$a_0=1$, $a_1=2$.

We could continue for curiosity, but it's not needed:

$a_2=7$, $a_3=26$, $a_4=97$, etc.

$x_1=2$, $y_1=1$, $D=3$.

$2^2-3\cdot 1^2=1$. The equality holds!

Therefore we can expect a Pell equation.

And indeed, $\frac{a_n^2-1}{3}$ with $n\ge 0$, $n\in\mathbb Z$ is always a perfect square.