# Proving that $f(n)$ is an integer for all integers n$\ge 0$

Tags: discrete-mathematics

We have the following function:
$$f(n)=\left(2+\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{2}\right)\left(2+\sqrt{2}\right)^{n}+\left(2-\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{2}\right)\left(2-\sqrt{2}\right)^{n}$$
I'm asked to prove that $f(n)$ is an integer for every integer $n\ge 0$.
I have no idea how to do this, can anyone help?

Comment: So $f(n)$ is a constant function?

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2156316/prove-that-left-frac3-sqrt172-rightn-left-frac3-sqrt172-r

Comment: Your right hand side expression does not contain n, is that correct?

Comment: Isn't it clear that however you expand it the odd powers of $\sqrt{2}$ cancel out? And that there are enough $2$'s floating around to kill off the $\frac{1}{2}$?

Comment: Try it for $n=1$ then use proof by induction and if that doesnt work try something else :)

Comment: The sequence $(f(n))$ solves $$f(0)=4\quad f(1)=10\quad f(n+2)=4f(n+1)-2f(n)$$

Comment: "I have no idea how to do this" Surely there is some lectures associated to this, what are their main results?

Comment: Glad to see the RHS was edited so it contained n...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With a hopefully clear notation,

$$f_n=A+B,$$
and
$$f_{n+1}=(2+\sqrt2)A+(2-\sqrt2)B$$ and

$$f_{n+2}=(2+\sqrt2)^2A+(2-\sqrt2)^2B\\
=(6+4\sqrt2)A+(6-4\sqrt2)B\\
=4f_{n+1}-2f_n.$$

As $f_0=4$ and $f_1=10$, all the next $f_n$ are integer.

Answer (score 0):

Use the Binomial Theorem and Pascal's Triangle to expand the $n$th powers. Then do the multiplications. ook at the integer terms and the square root terms. What will happen when you add?